# How to find out if mainboard is SATA compatible

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, sata, desktop-computer

Do you know any commands to find out the machine's maindoard is compatible to SATA? If not how can I examine it physically?

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visually, [SATA port motherboard](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=seamonkey-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&tbm=isch&q=sata+port+motherboard&revid=610204556&sa=X&ei=7kviTeOlHMPogQeR_4zWBg&ved=0CDgQ1QIoAA&biw=1280&bih=570).

Comment: You can likely just tell from opening the side of the case and looking at the drive cables.  SATA cables are thinner than IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Since SATA has been a standard for about 10 years now, the chances of the board not having SATA are low. Many older boards, even modern boards, by default setup SATA interfaces to Legacy IDE Emulation. I suggest using native AHCI, unless your OS is older than 5 to 7 yrs.

Answer (score 0):

Do `lspci`. One of my servers says (among others):

```
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA IDE Controller (rev 01)
```

Sometimes there's no clear description in the text and you need to google the controller type.

Comment: So is that IDE or SATA or SATA running in IDE "mode"?  Would SATA running AHCI be identified differently?  Searching isn't telling me, http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/sata-drive-ahci-issue-849601/ http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/pci:27C0:8086-IDE http://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/PCI

Answer (score 0):

Try `apt-get install lshw; lshw` from a root terminal and see if it tells you.  I'm thinking it might.